# linux. extend partition space with unallocated space BEFORE it

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, diskpart, fdisk

I have a dual boot (win + ubuntu).

How I can extend the disk space of `/dev/nvme0n1p6` (Ubuntu, is a partition of the current OS) with preceding free space?
[image]

I tried to do it with GParted but the right mouse button has no appropriate options on both partitions (unfortunately can't attach a screen with RMB)

Comment: Before you could *"extend"* the partition, you would first have to move it to the left (towards lower LBA numbers), and then extend the partition from the end (right side).  But moving a partition is *very* time consuming.  It is almost always faster to copy the partition to *another* drive, delete the original partition, create an empty partition over the unallocated area, and then copy the partition data back.  Of course, make a backup before you start.

Comment: You're looking at spending a lot of time just to gain 4.8GB of storage space.  You would probably be much better off using that 4+ GB area as the swap area, instead of that tiny area that you now have for swap.

Comment: Also you'll need to boot into a live environment that consists of gparted, since the partition you want to move is used for `/`.